# ImportError for SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, importerror

I am facing an issue.

I am trying to run a code which is given below. I am using tensorflow and numpy libraries.

```
def img_gen(pair_list, file):
    image = []
    for loc in pair_list:
        shutil.copy(loc, target_folder)
        img_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255)
        img_tranform = img_gen.flow_from_directory(temp_folder,
                                                   target_size=(112, 112),
                                                   batch_size=1,
                                                   class_mode='sparse',
                                                   shuffle=False,
                                                   color_mode='rgb',
                                                   seed=42)
        x_data, y_data = next(img_tranform)
        image.append(x_data)
        remove_file = os.path.join(target_folder,file)
        remove_file = remove_file.replace("\\", "/")
        os.remove(remove_file)
     return image


 img_class = []
 img_pairs = []
 for folders1, subfolders1, filenames1 in os.walk(orig_img_dir):
     for folders2, subfolders2, filenames2 in os.walk(segm_img_dir):
         for file1 in filenames1:
             for file2 in filenames2:
                 if file1.endswith('.png') and file1==file2:
                     audit_class = folders1.partition('\\')
                     audit_class = audit_class[-1]
                     img_class.append(audit_class)
                     file1_loc = os.path.join(folders1, file1)
                     file2_loc = os.path.join(folders2, file2)
                     img_pair = [file1_loc, file2_loc]
                     con_image = img_gen(img_pair, file1)
                     img = tf.concat([con_image[0][0], con_image[1][0]], axis=-1)
                     img_pairs.append(img)
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error

```
C:\Program Files\WinPython64-3.8.6\python-3.8.6.amd64\lib\site- 
packages\keras_preprocessing\image\affine_transformations.py in apply_affine_transform(x, 
theta, tx, ty, shear, zx, zy, row_axis, col_axis, channel_axis, fill_mode, cval, order)
    279     """
    280     if scipy is None:
--> 281         raise ImportError('Image transformations require SciPy. '
    282                           'Install SciPy.')
    283     transform_matrix = None

ImportError: Image transformations require SciPy. Install SciPy.
```

The SciPy is already installed  `scipy 1.5.3`

What can be the problem and also the possible solution?

Comment: I would suggest looking at what interpreter you are on the easy way to check if its installed is to do this import scipy print(scipy.__version__) but if its not try and switch interpret to the one who has it

Comment: Hey!
Thanks for the reply.
I checked and I am getting the version as 1.5.3

Comment: I opened another notebook and tried to import few libraries.
I am getting an error "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing qhull: The specified module could not be found."